# C# + WebBrowser + JavaScript - full load

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

Good time of day!:).Net 4.0, console. I need to write a parser page in console mode to get the code page in the form in which it is displayed to the user after download, without clicking the buttons, scrolling, and other events. I use this code, but it returns absolutely not what you need. In what ways can I get my desired result? I use other methods or components?

```
wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(linkNorm);
wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
wb.DocumentCompleted += new 
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(w_DocumentCompleted);
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
originalText = wb.DocumentText;
wb.Dispose(); 

void w_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(wb.DocumentText);
}
```

Change method to wb.Document.Body.OuterHtml - not help me. Result is so bad.

I think this is a pretty simple task, probably someone already solved.

Note - i need full HTML text in string-variable after work ALL JS

Comment: What *specifically* "doesn't work" in your attempt?  It sounds like what you're looking for is something called a "headless browser", which is an in-code browser-like tool which mimics a web browser (including executing JavaScript code).

Comment: Yes. Example - i see in browser (Chrome) content (text, not image or video), but i not see in loaded string. Content make by JS and not communications by user event (scroll or button click). I want load string after work all JS - WYSIWYG. Site for example - store http://brilliantov.net/index.php?route=product/product&path=76_86_88&product_id=24. Loaded content by JS - price

Comment: So, i find answer, but it`s local for my project

     while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
     {
        Application.DoEvents();
     }
    for (int i = 0; i < CallScripts.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    wb.Document.InvokeScript(CallScripts[i]);
                                }

Whe must learn original code and call all function manual. 

Maybe there is a more universal solution?